# Database query with unsaved changes included

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want a way to query for both entities in the DB and unsaved changes simultaneously. This code does the job, but it's at least ten times slower than just querying the DB. Any suggestions how I would go about this?

```
public ICollection<T> QueryWithLocal(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>> extra)
{
    if (extra != null)
    {
        var compiled = extra.Compile();
        compiled(GetAll(filter)).Load();
        var local = filter != null ?  _dbset.Local.AsQueryable().Where(filter) : _dbset.Local.AsQueryable();
        return compiled(local).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        GetAll(filter).Load();
        return filter != null ? _dbset.Local.AsQueryable().Where(filter).ToList() : _dbset.Local.ToList();
    }
}
```

`GetAll` just returns the DbSet, calling Where(filter) on it if the argument is not null.